# HAL_CAN_ERROR_PARAM with STM32f103c8t6 Bluepill and can bus

Tags: stm32, can-bus, stm32f1, stm32cubemx

I'm struggling to send messages via can bus with stm32f103 bluepill board and SN65HVD230 transceiver(terminated).
On the other end I use terminated usb can adapter, that works fine. CAN Bus speed is 500kbit/s.

Connections of SN65HVD230 :

```
PA11 -> RX
PA12 -> TX
GND -> GND
3.3V -> 3.3V
```

Configuration in CubeMX

```
RCC -> High Speed Clock = Crystal/Ceramic resonator
CAN -> Master mode
    Prescaler = 4
    Time Quanta in Bit Segment 1 = 13
    Time Quanta in Bit Segment 2 = 2
    Resyncronization jump width = 1
SYSCLK = 32 MHz
HCLK = 32 MHz
APB2 = 32 Mhz
APB1 = 32 Mhz
FCLK = 32 MHZ
```

Firmware version 1.8.0. Here is main.c

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "can.h"
#include "i2c.h"
#include "gpio.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef   TxHeader;
uint32_t              TxMailbox;
uint8_t TxData[8];
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void blink(int count, int duration);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_CAN_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  blink(3, 100);
  HAL_Delay(1000);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    TxHeader.StdId = 0x321;
    TxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
    TxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
    TxHeader.DLC = 4;
    TxHeader.TransmitGlobalTime = DISABLE;
    TxData[0] = 0;
    TxData[1] = 1;
    TxData[2] = 2;
    TxData[3] = 3;

    if (HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan, &TxHeader, TxData, &TxMailbox) == HAL_OK) {
      blink(1, 500);
    } else {
      blink(2, 100);
    }

    HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL8;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void blink(int count, int duration) {
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      HAL_Delay(duration / 2);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      HAL_Delay(duration / 2);
  }
}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

After 3 times of calling HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage 3 times (3 mailboxes?) in debugger is shows 0x200 error in hcan.ErrorCode, that is defined as HAL_CAN_ERROR_PARAM. It looks like all mailboxes are full and there are no messages sent into bus.

Any ideas how to debug this problem and get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The problemm seems to be the CAN TX buffer busy state, you can implement a time offset between can TX messages in order to let the driver to complete the transmission.

Answer (score 0):

I heard SN65HVD230 doesnt work with bluepill